# Asynchronous bulk find or create with ember.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js

How can I perform a bulk find or create with ember.js? This would be simple to do synchronously (foreach... continue if exists). But working with ember's asynchronous store creates lots of overhead in keeping track of the state of the operation.

Specifically, I have a variable to keep track of the number of objects waiting to be processed (`createIfNotExistTaskCounter`), so I can check when the store has finished working on all of the objects to be saved. And I use an array to keep track of the items stored so far (`createIfNotExistQueue`) - I can't let the store handle this task, because I can't count on an item being found after it has been saved.

Here's my best solution below (also on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/EguNoVI/2/edit?html,console)). Is there an easier way to do this?

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.LSAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'whitespace'
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: App.LSAdapter
});

App.Fruit = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string")
});


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  createIfNotExistTaskCounter: 0, // store number of items waiting to be processed
  createIfNotExistQueue: [],      // store a list of the items being added, to prevent duplicate adds

  setupController: function(controller) {
    /* This is a simplified version of a real task I'm trying to acomplish. The code adds a list of objects to the store, only creating them if they don't exist. After the list has been processed, the contents of the store are shown.

    To achieve this end I've used a counter and a queue to keep track of the operations' state. Is there a simpler way to do this? These overheads seem excessive for such a straightforward bulk insert operation.
    */
    var fruitToStore = ["apple", "pear", "banana", "apple"],
      store = this.get('store');

    this.set('createIfNotExistTaskCounter', fruitToStore.length);

    for(var i=0; i<fruitToStore.length; i++) {
      this.createIfNotExist(fruitToStore[i]);
    }
  },

  createListener: function() {
    if(this.get('createIfNotExistTaskCounter') !== 0) return;

    this.get('store').find('fruit').then(function(results) {

      // should only print three fruits, one of each type
      for (var i = 0; i < results.content.length; i++) {
        console.log(results.content[i].get('name'));
      };
    });

  }.observes('createIfNotExistTaskCounter'),


  createIfNotExist: function(f) {
    var store = this.get('store'),
      queue = this.get('createIfNotExistQueue'),
      that = this;

    // prevent duplicate records being created by adding every (distinct) item to a queue
    // the queue is used because there seems to be no way to tell if an item is already (asynchonously) being found / created / saved
    if(queue.indexOf(f) !== -1) {
      that.decrementProperty('createIfNotExistTaskCounter');
      return;
    }
    queue.push(f);


    // find or create
    store.find('fruit', {name: f}).then(function(results) {

      // found...
      if(results.get('length') !== 0) {
        that.decrementProperty('createIfNotExistTaskCounter');
        return;
      }

      // ...else create
      var fruit = store.createRecord('fruit', {name: f});
      fruit.save().then(function() {
        that.decrementProperty('createIfNotExistTaskCounter');
      }, function() {
        console.log("save failed!");
      });

    });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you return a promise from a `then` callback, you can create a chain of promises that behaves quite like a queue.

First you start with an already resolved callback, then you keep replacing it with a "then"-able object.

```
queue: new Ember.RSVP.resolve,
addToQueue: function() {
  this.queue = this.queue.then(function() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      // something that eventually calls resolve
    })
  })
}
```

Here's my updated JSBin of your code: http://jsbin.com/OtoZowI/2/edit?html,console

There is probably a way to make that much smaller if you can work out a way to return the existing find / save promises instead of creating a new one. I played with it a bit but I need to get back to work :P

Also, you can collect together a bunch of promises with RSVP.all and resolve only once they're all resolved. Depending on your actual code, this might be a much cleaner solution - do all the finds, wait until they're all resolved, then create the missing objects.

The RSVP docs have a good example of that here: https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/README.md#arrays-of-promises